# PSCS sharp:Smart card does not respond for send data (it returns 9F 0C - COMP 128)

Tags: c#, smartcard, apdu, sim-card, pcsc

This is my first question on stack, so please to be understanding for me. I'm working on project that concern communication of smart card with reader. I have got Dell Smart Card Reader Keyboard and SIM card.
My project is created using C# and pcsc-sharp.dll.

My problem is the lack of response from the card to the transmitted bit sequence. Below I added sequences that sent successively to the smart card and responses.

1. **Reader: Dell Smart Card Reader Keyboard 0**
2. **Command send:** A0 C0 00 00 20

   - Response: 00 00 1F 3E 3F 00 01 00 0F 55 FF 01 15 B1 05 09 05 00 83 8A 83 8A 00 8A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 (it's probably okay)
3. **Command send:** A0 A4 00 00 02 7F 20

   - Responde: 9F 22 (it's probably okay)
4. **Rand Data send:** 
   A0 88 00 00 10 09 05 01 0A 05 01 0D 06 00 0E 0E 08 00 0D 01 0A

   - Response: 9F 0C (it's probably okay)
5. **Command send:** A0 C0 00 00 0C

   - Response: 9F 0C **(here is bug, this is not response for data that has been sent)**

Does anybody know why is this happening? If anyone see any another bugs here, please described it. Below is **fragment** of my code in C#:

```
                    SCardContext context = new SCardContext();
                    context.Establish(SCardScope.System);

                    //Lista of available readers
                    string[] listOfReaders = context.GetReaders(); 

                    if (listOfReaders.Length <= 0)
                    {
                        throw new PCSCException(SCardError.NoReadersAvailable);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Reader: " + listOfReaders[0]);

                    }


                    SCardReader reader = new SCardReader(context);



                    SCardError error = reader.Connect(listOfReaders[0], SCardShareMode.Exclusive, SCardProtocol.T0 | SCardProtocol.T1);
                    CheckErr(error);

                    IntPtr transmissionProtocol;

                    switch (reader.ActiveProtocol)
                    {
                        case SCardProtocol.T0:
                            transmissionProtocol = SCardPCI.T0;
                            break;
                        case SCardProtocol.T1:
                            transmissionProtocol = SCardPCI.T1;
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new PCSCException(SCardError.ProtocolMismatch, reader.ActiveProtocol.ToString());
                    }


                    byte[] receivedData = new byte[256];


                    byte[] commandIntroduceYourself = new byte[] { 0xA0, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20 };

                    Console.Write("->");
                    for (int i = 0; i < commandIntroduceYourself .Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0:X2} ", start[i]);
                    }


                    error = czytnik.Transmit(transmissionProtocol, commandIntroduceYourself , ref receivedData);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write("<-");
                    for (int i = 0; i < receivedData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0:X2} ", receivedData[i]); 
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    //This command below was required by the professor. I don't know why...
                    byte[] commandNext = new byte[] { 0xA0, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x7F, 0x20 };
                    Console.Write("->");
                    for (int i = 0; i < commandNext.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0:X2} ", commandNext[i]);
                    }

                    error = czytnik.Transmit(transmissionProtocol, commandNext, ref receivedData);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write("<-");
                    for (int i = 0; i < receivedData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0:X2} ", receivedData[i]); 
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    int amountOfDataToRand = 16;

                    //This is my function, never mind
                        string data = Randomize.RandomData(amountOfDataToRand);
                        byte[] dataSendToCard = Randomize.StringToByteArray(data);

                        byte[] newArray = new byte[dataSendToCard.Length + 5];
                        //Below is sequence that should be added to data
                        dataSendToCard.CopyTo(newArray, 5);
                        newArray[0] = 0xA0;
                        newArray[1] = 0x88;
                        newArray[2] = 0x00;
                        newArray[3] = 0x00;
                        newArray[4] = 0x10;

                        dataSendToCard = newArray;

                    Console.WriteLine("\nData send: ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataSendToCard.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("{0:X2} ", dataSendToCard[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                       error = czytnik.Transmit(transmissionProtocol, dataSendToCard, ref receivedData);

                    CheckErr(error);

                    Console.Write("Data received: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < receivedData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0:X2} ", receivedData[i]); 
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();


                    byte[] commandGetResponse = new byte[] { 0xA0, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00,0x0c };
                    Console.Write("->");
                    for (int i = 0; i < commandGetResponse.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0:X2} ", commandGetResponse[i]);
                    }

                    error = czytnik.Transmit(transmissionProtocol, commandGetResponse, ref receivedData);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write("<-");
                    for (int i = 0; i < receivedData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0:X2} ", receivedData[i]); 
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
```

I read this document, but I didn't find answer. http://www.embedx.com/pdfs/ISO_STD_7816/info_isoiec7816-4%7Bed21.0%7Den.pdf

Comment: You might want to look into [this document](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/11/1111/05.03.00_60/gsmts_1111v050300p.pdf) as well. This behaviour is strange as card should return SRES/Kc instead of another `9F 0C`....Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately, Transmit function has wrong arguments.

Comment: So your problem is solved? I did check the arguments in the fragment in your post and it seemed correct to me.